# jstree dynamic JSON data from django

Tags: jquery, django, json, jstree

I'm trying to set up jsTree to dynamically accept JSON data from django.

This is the test data i have django returning to jstree:

```
result=[{ "data" : "A node", "children" : [ { "data" : "Only child", "state" : "closed" } ], "state" : "open" },"Ajax node"]
response=HttpResponse(content=result,mimetype="application/json")
```

this is the jstree code I'm using:

```
jQuery("#demo1").jstree({   
           "json_data" : {  
             "ajax" : {  
                "url" : "/dirlist",  
                "data" : function (n) {   
                    return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };   
                },
                 error: function(e){alert(e);}
             }  
         },  
        "plugins" : [ "themes","json_data"]
     });
```

All I get is the ajax loading symbol, the ajax error response is also triggered and it alerts "undefined".  I've also tried simpleJson encoding in django but with the same result.

If I change the url so that it is receiving a JSON file with identical data, it works as expected.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the problem was I hadn't done both simplejson encoding whilst including the application/JSON mimetype.

All sorted.